# Android Mapbox NavigationView is not loading map

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

In my app, I have integrated Mapbox and It was working fine. But now It's not loading a map in NavigationView. It is working fine in master branch but not working on the BLE features branch even though I have not changed anything in that Activity. Please find below code here, I am launching this NavigationActivity from MainActivity where user select origin and destination locations.

NavigationActivity-Screen:

[image]

NavigationActivity.java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.BannerText;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsRoute;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.LegStep;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationViewOptions;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.OnNavigationReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.instruction.InstructionLoader;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.milestone.BannerInstructionMilestone;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.milestone.Milestone;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.milestone.MilestoneEventListener;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.routeprogress.RouteProgress;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;


public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MilestoneEventListener, OnNavigationReadyCallback {

    private TextView myBanner;
    ImageView next, previous;
    List<LegStep> steps;
    TextView tv_step;
    int currentStepIndex = 0;
    DirectionsRoute currentRoute = null ;
    com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigations);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        myBanner = findViewById(R.id.dummyBanner);
        tv_step = findViewById(R.id.tv_step);
        next = findViewById(R.id.iv_next);
        previous = findViewById(R.id.iv_previous);
        navigationView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        navigationView.initialize(this);

        try{
            currentRoute = (DirectionsRoute) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("route");
            if(currentRoute != null){
                steps = currentRoute.legs().get(0).steps();
                if(steps.size() > 0){
                    setup();
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){}
    }

    private void setup(){

        loadText( 0);
        next.setOnClickListener((View v )-> {
            if (currentStepIndex < steps.size() - 2)
                loadText(++currentStepIndex);
        });
        previous.setOnClickListener((View v )-> {
            if (currentStepIndex > 0)
                loadText(--currentStepIndex);
        });
    }

    private void loadText( int index){

        BannerText bannerText = steps.get(index).bannerInstructions().get(0).primary();
        InstructionLoader loader = new InstructionLoader(tv_step, bannerText );
        loader.loadInstruction();
        String text = tv_step.getText().toString();
        String modifier = bannerText.modifier();
        String directionArrow = getDirectionArrow(text, modifier);
        if(!directionArrow.equals(""))
            tv_step.setText(directionArrow + text);
        tv_step.append(" " + getDistanceStr(steps.get(index).distance()));
        Log.d("Debugging modifier", bannerText.toJson());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationReady(boolean isRunning) {

        DirectionsRoute directionsRoute = (DirectionsRoute) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("route");

        NavigationViewOptions options = NavigationViewOptions.builder()
                .directionsRoute(directionsRoute)
                .shouldSimulateRoute(false)
                .milestoneEventListener(this)
                .build();
        navigationView.startNavigation(options);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMilestoneEvent(RouteProgress routeProgress, String instruction, Milestone milestone) {

        try {
            if (milestone instanceof BannerInstructionMilestone) {
                BannerText primaryInstruction = ((BannerInstructionMilestone) milestone).getBannerInstructions().primary();
                primaryInstruction.text();
                InstructionLoader loader = new InstructionLoader(myBanner, primaryInstruction);
                loader.loadInstruction();
                String text = myBanner.getText().toString();
                String modifier = primaryInstruction.modifier();
                String directionArrow = getDirectionArrow(text, modifier);
                if(!directionArrow.equals(""))
                    myBanner.setText(directionArrow + text);

                double distance = routeProgress.currentLegProgress().currentStep().distance();
                String distanceStr = getDistanceStr(distance);
                String milestoneString = myBanner.getText().toString() + distanceStr;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private String getDirectionArrow(String text, String modifier){
        Log.e("Debugging", text + "  " + modifier);
        if (text.contains("right") || modifier.contains("right"))
            return  ">  ";
        else if (text.contains("left") || modifier.contains("left"))
            return  "<  ";
        else if (text.contains("straight") || modifier.contains("straight"))
            return  "^  ";
        return "";
    }

    private String  getDistanceStr(double distance){
        if(distance > 1000)
            return " " + formatAmount(distance/1000) + " km";
        else return " " + distance + " m";
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        navigationView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        navigationView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        navigationView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!navigationView.onBackPressed()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        navigationView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        navigationView.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        navigationView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        navigationView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        navigationView.onDestroy();
    }

    public static String formatAmount(Double str){
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(str);
        bd = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        return bd.toString();
    }
}
```

activity_navigations.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="talha.niazi.hudlitenav.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/dummyBanner"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        android:textColor="@color/mapboxWhite"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/button_red"
        android:id="@+id/ll_nav"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30sp"
            android:tint="@color/white_color"
            android:id="@+id/iv_previous"
            mapbox:srcCompat="@drawable/previous"
            android:layout_height="30sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white_color"
            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10sp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/tv_step"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30sp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/iv_next"
            android:tint="@color/white_color"
            mapbox:srcCompat="@drawable/next"
            android:layout_height="30sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It would be great if you can help me to fix this weird issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set the content theme

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_NoActionBar);
```

before setting the contentView?

Also where did you set the style of NavigationView? You can do that in the layout XML file:

```
<com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:navigationDarkTheme="@style/CustomNavigationView"
    app:navigationLightTheme="@style/CustomNavigationView"
    app:navigationViewMapStyle="mapbox://styles/StyleURL"/>
```

Please use your custom styleURL.

Please let me know if it helped!

Comment: I also fetch same issue. What is custom styleURL and how to create? I am new to MapBox sdk please help me.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution in Kotlin**

For more information
This issue has been resolved here [Can’t start turn-by-turn navigation within custom NavigationViewActivity/NavigationViewFragment #1524](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/issues/1524)

First I updated the SDK version from **0.13.0** to **0.23.0**

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.23.0'
```

The dependency will transitively bring in the Maps SDK and the core navigation libraries. This helps prevents conflicts.

In project root build.gradle don't forget to add

```
maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }
```

in **fragment_navigation.xml**

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="NavigationViewFragment">

    <com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**In NavigationViewFragment**

**originPoint** and **destinationPoint** is variable type   Point.fromLngLat(longitude,latitude)

```
 class NavigationViewFragment : Fragment(), OnNavigationReadyCallback, NavigationListener {

    private lateinit var navigationView: NavigationView
    var directionsRoute: DirectionsRoute? = null

     override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
       .....
     }

     override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.navigationView) as NavigationView
        navigationView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val initialPosition = CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(LatLng(originPoint.longitude(), originPoint.latitude()))
            .zoom(18.0)
            .build()
        navigationView.initialize(this, initialPosition)
     }

    override fun onNavigationReady(isRunning: Boolean) {
        val origin = Point.fromLngLat(originPoint.longitude() , originPoint.latitude())
        val destination = Point.fromLngLat(destinationPoint.longitude(), destinationPoint.latitude())
        calculateRoute(origin, destination)
    }

    override fun onCancelNavigation() {
         // Do something 
    }

    override fun onNavigationFinished() {
       // Do something 
    }

    override fun onNavigationRunning() {
        // Do something 
    }

    private fun calculateRoute(origin: Point , destination: Point) {
        NavigationRoute.builder(this.context)
              .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken()!!)
              .origin(origin)
              .destination(destination)
              .build()
              .getRoute( object : Callback<DirectionsResponse> { //import retrofit2.Callback

                // Send request to Direction API
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<DirectionsResponse>? , t: Throwable?) { 
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<DirectionsResponse>? ,
                                        response: Response<DirectionsResponse>?) {
                    if (response?.body() == null || response.body()?.routes()?.size!! < 1) {
                        return
                    }
                    directionsRoute = response.body()!!.routes()[0]
                    startNavigation()
                }
            })
    }

    private fun startNavigation() {
        if (directionsRoute == null) return
        val options = NavigationViewOptions.builder()
              .directionsRoute(directionsRoute)
              .shouldSimulateRoute(true)
              .navigationListener(this)
              .build()

        // start camera zooms to the beginning of the route
        navigationView.startCamera(directionsRoute)
        navigationView.startNavigation(options)
    }
}
```

Comment: Bacar Pereira, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)